# MDX Case Statement without break

Tags: case, mdx

Is there a way to use an MDX Case Statement without the break functionality?
In the example below, I want for [Measures].[Count] = 7 to show both "MEDIUM" AND" LARGE" (or just "LARGE" if it's possible) not only "MEDIUM".

```
  CASE 
  WHEN [Measures].[Count] > 4 THEN 'MEDIUM'   
  WHEN [Measures].[Count] > 6 THEN 'LARGE'
  WHEN [Measures].[Count] > 3 THEN 'SMALL'
  ELSE "NONE"
  END
```

Comment: Can you give some context where you would need this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should reorder you `WHEN` clauses, as in MDX (like in SQL), the first clause that matches wins:

```
CASE 
  WHEN [Measures].[Count] > 6 THEN 'LARGE'
  WHEN [Measures].[Count] > 4 THEN 'MEDIUM'   
  WHEN [Measures].[Count] > 3 THEN 'SMALL'
  ELSE "NONE"
END
```

would return 'LARGE' for 7.

You cannot return more than one value from a `CASE` expression. `CASE` is an expression (even if the MS documentation wrongly calls it statement in some places). And an expression can have only one result.

Imagine you write an Excel formula (which is also an expression). You have only one cell to display the result, so the formula can only deliver one result.

But of course, the result could be a combination of several results, like a string concatenation. Or in the case of the `CASE` expression, you could return sets which can have one or more members. But even then you would need different `WHEN` branches, each just returning one set.